# xCode no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, json, xcode, arduino

Есть массив объектов в формате json. Что то не могу запустить функцию удаления дубликатов объектов. Что не так делаю, подскажите.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include "ArduinoJson.h"

void removeDuplicates(JsonArray& array) {
    std::set<std::string> seenValues;
    for (JsonArray::iterator it = array.begin(); it != array.end(); ++it) {
        JsonObject& element = *it;
        bool isNew = seenValues.insert(element["K"]).second;
        if (!isNew) array.remove(it);
        std::cout << element["K"] << std::endl;
    }
}


int main() {
    char json[] = "[{\"K\":\"1\"},{\"K\":\"2\"},{\"K\":\"1\"},{\"K\":\"1\"},{\"K\":\"2\"}]";
    DynamicJsonBuffer jb;
    JsonArray& IPList = jb.parseArray(json);
    removeDuplicates(IPList);

    std::cout << IPList << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор ругается Call to member function 'insert' is ambiguous на строке bool isNew = ...

Comment: Если компилятор говорит о неоднозначности вызова, то он обычно в сообщении указывает, какие функции привели к неоднозначности. Так что приведите полностью сообщение компилятора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом вызове функции `removeDuplicates`

```
std::string out = removeDuplicates(json);
```

вызывается конструктор преобразования, который из объекта типа `char *`, в который неявно преобразуется символьный массив `json`,  строит временный объект типа `JsonArray`. Вы не можете привязывать неконстантную ссылку к временному объекту. Поэтому компилятор не может вызывать объявленную вами функцию и ищет функцию, которую он мог бы вызвать для временного объекта. Такой функции нет, и компилятор об этом сообщает.

Возможным решением в этом случае может быть создание объекта типа `JsonArray` в `main` и использование его в качестве аргумента. Например,

```
JsonArray array( json );
std::string out = removeDuplicates( array );
```

Что касается второго сообщения об ошибке, то оно является следствием того, какой тип имеет объект, возвращаемый оператором `element["K"]`. Похоже, этот объект не имеет тип `std::string`, а потому вследствии возможных неявных преобразований возникает неоднозначность вызова функции-члена класса `insert` для этого объекта.

Вам надо посмотреть по документации, какой тип имеет возвращаемое значение оператора в вашем случае и вызывать функцию `insert` , правльно задав выражение аргумента, возможно указав явные для него преобразования, чтобы исключить неоднозначность.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался! Может кому то пригодится.

В основе работы с JSON данными лежит библиотека [ArduinoJson](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson). Она работает на всех Arduino (Uno, Due, Mini, Micro, Yun...), ESP8266, Teensy, Intel Edison and Galileo, PlatformIO, Energia, RedBearLab boards (BLE Nano...), ОС (Windows, Linux, OSX...)

Это пример алгоритма, который принимает массив объектов в формате json и удаляет из нее объекты, в которых значение указанного ключа будет одинаковое.

Пример:

1. Вход: [{"staIP":"1"},{"staIP":"2"},{"staIP":"2"},{"staIP":"3"},{"staIP":"1"}]
2. Выход: [{"staIP":"1"},{"staIP":"2"},{"staIP":"3"}]

Ответ в консоли:

```
Source: [{"staIP":"1"},{"staIP":"2"},{"staIP":"2"},{"staIP":"3"},{"staIP":"1"}]
Test:        v:New         v:New         v:Rep         v:New         v:Rep     
IPList: [{"staIP":"1"},{"staIP":"2"},{"staIP":"3"}]
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include "ArduinoJson.h"

void removeDuplicates(JsonArray& arr, std::string Key) {
    std::set<std::string> seenValues;
    std::cout << "Test:    ";
    for (JsonArray::iterator it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); ++it) {
        JsonObject& element = *it;
        bool isNew = seenValues.insert(element[Key].as<char*>()).second;
        if (!isNew) {
            arr.remove(it);
            std::cout << "    v:Rep     ";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "    v:New     ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::string json = "";
    json += "[{\"staIP\":\"1\"},{\"staIP\":\"2\"},{\"staIP\":\"2\"},{\"staIP\":\"3\"},{\"staIP\":\"1\"}]";
    std::cout << "Source: " << json << std::endl;   // Вывод json в консоль

    DynamicJsonBuffer jb;                           // Создаем динамический буфер jsonBuffer
    JsonArray& arr = jb.parseArray(json);           // Парсим строку json и создаем из нее массив IPList
    removeDuplicates(arr,"staIP");                  // Удаление объектов из массива IPList, если значению ключа K одинаковое

    std::string IPList = "";                        // Создаем строковую переменную для хранения конечного результата
    arr.printTo(IPList);                            // Преобразование json в строку
    std::cout << "IPList: " << IPList << std::endl; // Вывод jsonStr в консоль
    return 0;                                       // Функция возвращает 0
}
```